# pyqt5でドラッグ&ドロップで画像を取得、表示したい

Tags: python3, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5を用いてウィンドウに画像をドラッグ&ドロップした時にその画像が表示されるようにしたいです。しかし、jpg画像をドラッグしてもドロップ可能の表示が出ません。当然ドロップしても何も起こりません。イメージとしては、下図のように左上の領域に画像をドラッグ&ドロップした時に、ウィンドウの中央にその画像が表示されるようにしたいです。

しかし、画像をドラッグしてもドロップ可能のマークが出ません。当然、ドロップしても何も起こりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QWidget,
    QLineEdit, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Button(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        #print(e.mimeData().formats())
    
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat(e.mimeData().formats()):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()
        

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(event.mimeData().imageData())) 


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        button = Button("",self)
        button.resize(100,100) 
        button.setIcon(QIcon("drdr.png")) 
        button.setIconSize(QSize(100,100))
        button.move(0, 0)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('image.png'))
        self.label.move(150,150)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/103331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像をドラッグした際に、ドロップした際のデータ(この場合画像データ)を`QMimeData`オブジェクトに設定し、さらに`QDrag`オブジェクトを作成し`exec`メソッドを呼び出す必要があります。
(参考: [QtのDrag and Dropの解説](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html))

こんな感じでしょうか。
(`QLabel`を拡張したクラスの`mousePressEvent`メソッドをオーバーライドするイメージです。また「画像データ」は何かしらの`QPixmap`オブジェクトのイメージです)

```
def mousePressEvent(e):
    mimeData = QMimeData()
    mimeData.setPixmap(画像データ)
    drag = QDrag(self)
    drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
    # これはドラッグ操作中に画像を表示するために設定している
    drag.setPixmap(画像データ)
    drag.exec()
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！