# PyQt5のhasImageメソッドで画像が認識されません

Tags: python, pyqt5

ウインドウに画像をドラッグ＆ドロップして表示するだけのプログラムが作りたいのですが、下のコードで実行してローカルの画像を入れると、
`True False False True False`
と出力されます。つまり、画像が画像データとして認識されません。どの拡張子の画像でも認識されませんでした。ウェブからのドラッグでも認識されませんでした。おそらくPC側の問題ではないかと思うのですが、よくわかりません。
同様の質問が見当たらなかったので、非常に初歩的な質問するまでもない問題だと思うのですが、自分にはどうしても原因がわかりません。原因がわかる方、よろしくお願いします。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
 
        self.setGeometry(300, 50, 400, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')

        self.show()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e): 
            e.accept()
    
    def dropEvent(self,e):
        print(e.mimeData().hasText(),e.mimeData().hasHtml(),e.mimeData().hasImage(),e.mimeData().hasUrls(),e.mimeData().hasColor())
        label = QLabel()
        pix = QPixmap(e.mimeData().imageData())
        label.setPixmap(pix)
        self.vbl.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `hasUrls()` の結果が `True` になっていますので、`print(e.mimeData().urls())` も実行してみて下さい。おそらく画像ファイルの URI が表示されると思います。

Comment: 古い記事ですがこれの内容ではないですか？ teratail:[pyqt5でドラッグ&ドロップで画像を取得、表示したい](https://teratail.com/questions/103331), stackoverflow:[pyqt5でドラッグ&ドロップで画像を取得、表示したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40065/26370)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドロップされたデータから画像のパス名を取り出して、イメージを作成する必要があるのだと思います。
`dropEvent()`を次のように書き換えればうまくいくと思います。
※確認したのはWindowsです。

```py
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        import urllib.request
        print(e.mimeData().hasText(), e.mimeData().hasHtml(), e.mimeData().hasImage(), e.mimeData().hasUrls(),
              e.mimeData().hasColor())
        label = QLabel()
        path = urllib.request.url2pathname(e.mimeData().urls()[0].path())
        image = QImage(path)
        pix = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        label.setPixmap(pix)
        self.vbl.addWidget(label)
```

Windowsのパス名はドライブ名の先頭に`/`が付加されてしまいます。
`urllib.request.url2pathname`で削除しています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911052/urlparse-on-a-windows-file-scheme-uri-leaves-extra-slash-at-start

---

metropolisさんから次のコメントがありました。

> ウェブブラウザから画像をドラッグ・アンド・ドロップする場合、そのコードでは何も表示されないのでご注意を。

このような使い方をすることを全然考えていませんでした。調べてみたところ次の記事を見つけました。
https://qiita.com/y-chan/items/7d99a3dc3f1cc55dad6a
この記事を参考にしたコードを書いてみたところ、ネット上の画像が表示されました。

```py
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasHtml():
            import requests
            import base64
            url = e.mimeData().urls()[0].toString()
            data = base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content).decode()
            label = QLabel(f"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{data}\"/>")
            self.vbl.addWidget(label)
        else:
            import urllib.request
            label = QLabel()
            path = urllib.request.url2pathname(e.mimeData().urls()[0].path())
            image = QImage(path)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
            label.setPixmap(pix)
        self.vbl.addWidget(label)
```

Comment: URI をローカルのファイルパスに変換する `QUrl.toLocalFile()` メソッドが提供されています。それと、ウェブブラウザから画像をドラッグ・アンド・ドロップする場合、そのコードでは何も表示されないのでご注意を。

Answer (score 0):

既に解決済みですが、参考までに別回答を投稿します。

※ `User-Agent` を指定しているのは `HTTP status code 403(Forbidden)` を回避するためのものです

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    request_headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0'
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
 
        self.setGeometry(300, 50, 400, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')

        self.show()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e): 
        e.accept()
    
    def dropEvent(self,e):
        if e.mimeData().hasImage():
            pix = QPixmap(e.mimeData().imageData())
        elif e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            url = e.mimeData().urls()[0]
            if url.isLocalFile():
                pix = QPixmap(url.toLocalFile())
            else:
                # remote file
                try:
                    req = Request(url.toString(), headers=self.__class__.request_headers)
                    data = urlopen(req).read()
                except:
                    return
                pix = QPixmap()
                pix.loadFromData(data)
                # (pix := QPixmap()).loadFromData(data)
        else:
            # nothing to do
            return

        # return if the iamge file does not exist or is of an unknown format
        if pix.isNull(): return

        # clear all widgets in QVBoxLayout
        for i in reversed(range(self.vbl.count())): 
            w = self.vbl.itemAt(i).widget()
            self.vbl.removeWidget(w)
            w.setParent(None)

        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(pix)
        self.vbl.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```